# HTTP request with NTLM authentication in Julia

Tags: python, http, julia, ntlm, ntlm-authentication

Is there a way the execute an HTTP request that requires an NTLM authentication with Julia.
As far as I know, `HTTP.jl` does not support it natively.

For reference, in my case, the python equivalent is

```py
import requests
import json
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

body_string = json.dumps(body, indent=4)
json_object = json.dumps({"inputJson": body_string})

response = requests.post(
    url, 
    data=json_object,
    headers= {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    auth=HttpNtlmAuth(domain_username, password)
)
```

where `body`, `url`, `domain_username` and `password` are variables defined beforehand.